# EJB3 Weblogic 10.3.6 JNDI lookup

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, weblogic, ejb-3.0, jndi

I am getting a javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: While trying to look up a EJB3 Stateless session bean.

I have 1 weblogic domain and it consists of two servers Server_1 and server_2. I have deployed a EAR file to server_2 which consists of a EJB3 deployment. It has the following inside it

```
EJB3 EAR file
----EJB3 Module Jar file
    ------Stateless session EJB3 bean 
----META-INF Folder
    -- application.xml file
----lib folder
    -------EJB3 Client jar holding containing remote  and local interface
```

The EJB3 Module jar file consists of following

```
EJB3 JAR file
    ----package structure of EJB3 Stateless bean and bean 
    ----META-INF folder
        -----weblogic-ejb-jar.xml
        -----ejb-jar.xml.
```

On server 1 I have deployed my EJB3 Client Jar which has my remote interface inside it. On this server I have also 
deployed another jar file which will use the remote interface of the client jar to lookup the ejb.

my EJB3 is below

```
@Remote
public interface ContractorIdRemote {
    public String test();
}

@Stateless(name="ContractorIdBean", mappedName="ContractorIdBean")
public class ContractorIdBean implements ContractorIdRemote {

    public String test() {
        .........
    }
}
```

my ejb-jar file is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ASCII"?>
<ejb-jar xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:ejb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_0.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
<display-name>ejb</display-name>
<enterprise-beans>
     <session>
          <ejb-name>ContractorIdBean</ejb-name>
          <ejb-ref>
               <ejb-ref-name>ContractorIdBean</ejb-ref-name>
               <remote>com.ejb3.websphere.ContractorIdRemote</remote>
               <mapped-name>ContractorIdBean</mapped-name>
          </ejb-ref>
     </session>
</enterprise-beans>
</ejb-jar>
```

the weblogic-ejb xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE weblogic-ejb-jar PUBLIC
'-//BEA Systems, Inc.//DTD WebLogic 6.0.0 EJB//EN'
'http://www.bea.com/servers/wls600/dtd/weblogic-ejb-jar.dtd'>

<weblogic-ejb-jar>


    <weblogic-enterprise-bean>
        <ejb-name>ContractorIdBean</ejb-name>
        <jndi-name>ejb/ContractorIdBean</jndi-name>
    </weblogic-enterprise-bean>



</weblogic-ejb-jar>
```

My lookup is done as follows from the calling client

```
Context ctx = new InitialContext(properties);
ContractorIdRemote cRemote = (ContractorIdRemote)ctx.lookup("ejb/ContractorIdBean");
cRemote.test();
```

my properties file has the following

```
java.naming.factory.initial=weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory
java.naming.provider.url=t3://localhost:17001
```

But obviously ejb/ContractorIdBean is not what it is bound with. I can see the EAR is deployed on server_2 successfully

Can anyone please advice what I should use to lookup the ejb. I have tried the following but all with namenotfound exception

```
java:comp/env/ejb/ejb/ContractorIdBean
java:comp/env/ejb/ContractorIdBean
```

Thanks in advance

UPDATE:

I changed my jndi name to just contractorIdBean and as before I can see in the jndi tree on the server the binding name ContractorIdBean#com.ejb3.websphere.ContractorIdRemote

But this still throws a Name not found exception

[image]

UPDATE AGAIN:

I changed the jndi name to the screenshot above and added the security credentials for the server. Following this I get the following exception now

```
javax.naming.CommunicationException [Root exception is java.rmi.UnmarshalException: failed to unmarshal class java.lang.Object; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ejb3.websphere.ContractorIdRemote]
```

I am not sure why it cannot find the class. I have also included it in the deployed EAR file on server_2 as well as in the ejb client jar on server 1

Answer (score 1):

For a remote lookup (one server to another) you should do something like the following:

```
Hashtable<String, String> h = new Hashtable<String, String>();
h.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");
h.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, url);
h.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, username);
h.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);

InitialContext context = new InitialContext(h);
cId= (ContractorIdRemote) context.lookup("ejb/ContractorIdBean");
```

Weblogic does not prefix JNDI names with `comp/env` so you do not need that. I believe that is used for Tomcat.

Comment: So I added the two properties that you mentioned above but still get the same exception. NameNotFound.